# Prove that $C=\{\alpha<\omega_1:\ \textrm{ot}(\alpha\times\alpha, \preceq)=\alpha\}\in club_{\omega_1}$

Tags: set-theory

How would you show that $C=\{\alpha<\omega_1:\ \textrm{ot}(\alpha\times\alpha, \preceq)=\alpha\}\in club_{\omega_1}$ (closed and unbounded in $\omega_1$)? $\preceq$ is the maximolexicographic (?) order, i.e. $$(a,b)\preceq(c,d) \iff \max(a,b)<\max(c,d) \vee (\max(a,b)=\max(c,d) \wedge (a,b) \leq_{lex} (c,d))$$

I don't understand a basic thing here -- namely, how can one define order type of a set which is not well-ordered? Because I believe this $\preceq$ order is not a well order in general.

Other than that, what I thought of is to show that $\textrm{ot}$ is increasing, continuous and satisfies $\textrm{ot}(\alpha\times\alpha,\preceq) \geq \alpha$. Then the set of fixed points of this mapping could serve as a club (this would still require image of $\textrm{ot}$ to be defined as $\omega_1$). It is rather trivial to notice the function is increasing and (I think) that is satisfies this third constraint. But the continuity? I'm unable to say anything constructive without shaking my hands too much.

Comment: You have continuity as set inclusion in the product side. This should be fairly easy to use to get the wanted result.

Comment: Could you clarify please? I don't understand.

Comment: If $\alpha_n\to\alpha$, then $\bigcup \alpha_n\times\alpha_n=\alpha\times\alpha$.

Comment: Ok, I tried but still failed. How do we know that $\sup\textrm{ot}(...) = \textrm{ot}(\sup...)$?

Comment: The well-orderings form *end-extensions* of one another. The part of $\alpha_{n+1}\times\alpha_{n+1}\setminus\alpha_n\times\alpha_n$ is a *tail segment* of $\alpha_{n+1}\times\alpha_{n+1}$. And you can actually show that the order type of that tail segment is in fact $\alpha_{n+1}$.

Comment: So are you saying that this is also trivial modulo the fact that $\sup$ is the sum?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying. Although not trivial, it relies on nontrivial facts. It's only trivial after the fact. :-)

Comment: Thank you! But while we're still at it - could you tell me how can one define order type of a set with some order already imposed, like in here? As far as I understand $(\alpha\times\alpha,\preceq)$ might not be a well-order for some $\alpha$ so how... What is happening?

Comment: How could it *not* be well-ordered for some $\alpha$? It just could be "slightly" longer than $\alpha$. But that's not an actual issue.

Comment: Oh, ok, so I just have to notice it is in fact a well-order. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jules: Every countable dense linear order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$ with its usual order, so all of these orders represent a single order type, commonly denoted by $\eta$. Clearly this order type is not a well-order. An order type is basically just an isomorphism class of linear orders; it just happens that we have nice canonical representatives of the well-ordered order types.

Comment: @Brian: Admittedly, I'm not sure what your comment has to do with the question. Is it about the general notion of order types? If so, why only bring up $\eta$ and not other order type (or some theorem stating that every countable order type is such and such summation of ordinals, their inverse and $\eta$, which I vaguely recall to be a thing)?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, I was pointing out that the notion of order type is not limited to the well-ordered order types. I stopped with $\eta$ because it's relatively familiar, and one example seemed sufficient, especially since the comment was already getting a bit long.